# Uncontrollable Sleep? PHP

Tags: php

I understand how sleep works, But it works before something happens. Say for example I have a few echos and mail and some other things. Then have a sleep, then a redirect. Well, it looks like the sleep goes first, then everything just spam at once and cause server cpu increase. Is there something that is similar to sleep, that will not act after things have not been executed?

for example

```
echo 'Hey';
sleep(3);
echo 'My next text after 3 seconds is up';
```

well, with this, This does not work, and it does the same thing using C#.

When this happens, the page will not respond for 3 seconds, then both messages "Hey" & "My next text after 3 seconds is up" will show all at once. Is im using this for the wrong thing? Is there something else I should use?

Since I have never used sleep, and I seen alot of people use this for the same thing and it works, but in my case, it does not really works the way I thought it would.

PHP not C#

Comment: This happens when the response is *buffered*. In any case this is *not* an appropriate use of sleep, and it is invalid to issue a redirect after writing other headers (so it would break if it was not buffered).

Comment: Is there anything else other than sleep I could use? Or is buffer is what I should use? Because I used ob_start and flush when I used sleep, but still ended up with the same results

Comment: Really one should generate (and return) all the HTTP/HTML response as fast as possible, ie. without sleep. I'm not sure what sleep is attempting to solve here; and as per above, even when writing immediately, it is invalid to issue a redirect after such output has started.

Comment: Mhm, So using JavaScript/jQuery may be best to use in this situation.

Comment: Without knowing more detail, I'm guessing you need to simply move the redirect to JavaScript, so that the delay is on the client side, not the server side.

Comment: Using AJAX *may* be a viable solution.. but that really depends on what the problem actually is.

Comment: Ok, Because if I could not find anything else replace of sleep for php, I was deciding to use javascript. But, I might just wait and see if anyone else have anything for me.

Comment: well in this simple case (echoing hey first, sleep 3sec, then echo another one), have you tried flushing the first echo? like this: http://pastebin.com/qDpwanpx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via flushing the output at points. You can also use [`ob_implicit_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) for this purpose which would ensure that output will be flushed at each output call without explicit calls for flush.

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Hey';

for($i=0;$i<60;$i++){
    echo "<br />My next text after $i seconds is up";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Note that [`php docs for ob_flush suggests`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109314) that you should try putting content-type header when things are not working. But above code worked without that also.

Answer (score 0):

It runs exactly as it was programmed, the thing is, the output is being buffered. You have to disable buffering, and force a `flush()` to make sure its sent before the `sleep()`.

```
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // closes all existing buffers if any
echo 'Hey';
flush(); // make sure it was flushed to the client
sleep(3);
...
```

And still it might not work in all cases, because theres another buffer, and this one you cannot control: the browser. Some browsers will not render any HTML unless it has received a certain minimum amount of data.